# How can I collect output from a parallelised Python operation in a single list?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to run an operation in parallel and colelct the output in a global list. I include the list as a variable that is passed to the parallel script. However, the output doesn't accumulate there. Why doesn't this work?

This is the 1st cell in Jupyter Notebook:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


def tenfold(input_value,output_list):
    output_value = input_value *10
    print(input_value, output_value)
    output_list.append(output_value)

# list to collect output
out_list = []

#create input tuples
tups = []
for i in range(0,5): tups.append((i, out_list))
        
# parallel 
def main():
    cores = os.cpu_count()
    workers = 30
    print('n cores: ', cores, ', n workers: ', workers)
    with Pool(workers) as p:
        p.map(tenfold, tups) # second variable must be a tuple

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then when I run this cell:

```
print(out_list)
```

I get an error in the terminal:

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'tenfold' on <module '**main**'
> (built-in)>

And the kernel just sits there doing nothing until I restart it. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to collect the output from a function run in parallel in a global list?

Comment: map's second argument must be an iterable, which can be a tuple, in your case a list of tuples.

Comment: *tups* is not available in the sub-process's address space. Use multiprocessing.Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tups* is not available in the sub-process's address space. Here's an example of how you could append to a [managed] list. You can adapt this to your needs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def add_to_list(the_list, the_value):
    the_list.append(the_value)


def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        myList = manager.list()
        pool = Pool()
        for i in range(10):
            pool.apply_async(add_to_list, (myList, i))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(myList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output (example):**

```
[0, 4, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 9, 8]
```

A much simpler approach would be to return the value(s) you're interested in from the subprocess then create your list in the main program.

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

N = 5

def tenfold(x):
    return x * 10

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        myList = pool.map_async(tenfold, range(N)).get()
        print(myList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: Great, that does it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting all these work on my Ubuntu machine with Python 3.10.12 but not on the Windows virtual machine I use for work with Python 3.9.12. How vexing.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with passing `out_list` to the paralelaised function and appending to it inside, I'm not sure, never really figured out threading myself.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


def tenfold(input_value):
    output_value = input_value *10
    print(input_value)
    return output_value
        
# parallel 
def main():
    cores = os.cpu_count()
    workers = 30
    print('n cores: ', cores, ', n workers: ', workers)
    with Pool(workers) as p:
        out_list = p.map(tenfold, list(range(0,5))) # second variable must be a tuple
    print(out_list)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works, you can just return the value in the functions since `map()` will return a list of the workers functions returns.